# How can I execute the salt state git.latest with password protected private key

Tags: linux, github, provisioning, salt-stack

I'm using [salt](http://www.saltstack.com/) to pull a git repo.

```
myrepo:
   git.latest:
     - rev: master
     - target: home/myuser/myapp
     - runas: myuser
```

I have added an id_rsa file into `/home/myuser/.ssh/`, including the private key to authenticate to github. If this private key is not password protected the above git.latest state works fine.

If the private key is password protected (as it should be) the above `git.latest` state fails with the error message `"fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"`. The reason that this state fails is that the system is asking for the private key password.

Now I'm wondering how I could tell my salt master to provide the password to the password protected private key. I think it should somehow work with a linux key chain util - or is there even some similar functionality build-in within saltstack?

Comment: Personally, you should use a deploy key for that repo. You're either trying to protect a key on the box or protect a password in memory. Both are accessible, only one can be revoked.

Comment: I don't think the `git.latest` state has any sort of password-handling in place.  It's probably possible to add, though.  You're welcome to open an issue.

Comment: Will do so. It would be really nice if a password handling feature is build-in. Might work somehow using the authentication agent forwarding feature of ssh (ssh - A).

Comment: Done: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/8625

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you use special key used only for that purpose. Github offers deploy keys for this very scenario: https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys

They are easily set up and easily revoked.